# How could I remove a specific object in an array from localStorage by user button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I have many Objects in my localStorage array. These Objects have different properties, like firstName, lastName, and so on. Each propertie nested in a div. In my object div, is also a button with id=hide and an paragraph "x".
I saved my objects "Person" in an array "persons". So how could i call the specific object by user button click (the "x") and remove it from localStorage? I know the method localStorage.removeItem. But i don't get the key's and value parameters to get the specific object (by user button click the "x" of this object).
I know also, if i set specific id's to each object to call it. but not with these button and user click.

Thanks for your support! - And of course there are more fixes to do in my script but first i need the removeItem-method -

I take my script inside here.

```js
class Person{
    firstName;
    lastName;
    birthDate;
    age;
    adress;
    zipCode;
    city;
    phoneNumber;
};

const persons = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

    
    var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persons'));

    if (arr != null) {
        arr.forEach(function (obj) {
            $(".flexBox").append('<div class="flexContact"><div class="flexElement">' + obj.firstName + '</div><div class="flexElement">' + obj.lastName + '</div><div class="flexElement">' + obj.birthDate + '</div><div class="flexElement">' + obj.age + '</div><div class="flexElement">' + obj.adress + '</div><div class="flexElement">' + obj.zipCode + '</div><div class="flexElement">' + obj.city + '</div ><div class="flexElement">' + obj.phoneNumber + '</div > <button id="hide">X</button></div > ')
        })  
    }
    
    
    $("#submit").click(function () {



        const newPerson = new Person()

            newPerson.firstName = $("#firstName").val(),
            newPerson.lastName = $("#lastName").val(),
            newPerson.birthDate = $("#birthDate").val(),
            newPerson.age = $("#age").val(),
            newPerson.adress = $("#adress").val(),
            newPerson.zipCode = $("#zipCode").val(),
            newPerson.city = $("#city").val(),
            newPerson.phoneNumber = $("#phoneNumber").val(),


            persons.push(newPerson);
        
        $(".flexBox").append('<div class="flexContact"><div class="flexElement">' + newPerson.firstName + '</div><div class="flexElement">' + newPerson.lastName + '</div><div class="flexElement">' + newPerson.birthDate + '</div><div class="flexElement">' + newPerson.age + '</div><div class="flexElement">' + newPerson.adress + '</div><div class="flexElement">' + newPerson.zipCode + '</div><div class="flexElement">' + newPerson.city + '</div ><div class="flexElement">' + newPerson.phoneNumber + '</div > <button id="hide">X</button></div > ');


            
    });

    $(".flexContact #hide").click(function () {
        $(this).parents(".flexContact").hide("slow");

        JSON.stringify(localStorage.removeItem('persons #hide', ".flexContact"));
        
    });

    $("#set").click(function () {

        localStorage.setItem('persons', JSON.stringify(persons));

    });
});
```

```css
h1
{
    text-align: center
}
.flexBox
{
    display: table;
}
.flexTitles 
{
    display: table-row;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    background-color: burlywood;
}
.flexContact
{
    display: table-row;
    break-after: column;
}
.flexElement
{
    display: table-cell;
    border: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
#hide 
{
    background-color: red;   
}
#firstName, #lastName, #birthDate, #age, #adress, #zipCode, #city, #phoneNumber 
{
    display: table-cell;
    border: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Contact List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Alight.Mew.ContactList.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Alight.Mew.ContactList.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contact List</h1>
    <div class="flexBox">
        <div class="flexTitles">
            <div class="flexElement">
                <p>Vorname</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flexElement">
                <p>Nachname</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flexElement">
                <p>Geburtsdatum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flexElement">
                <p>Alter</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flexElement">
                <p>Anschrift</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flexElement">
                <p>Postleitzahl</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flexElement">
                <p>Ort</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flexElement">
                <p>Telefonnummer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /> 
        Vorname:        <input type="text" size="20" minlength="2" maxlength="40" name="firstName" id="firstName" /><br />
        Nachname:       <input type="text" size="20" minlength="2" maxlength="40" name="lastName" id="lastName" /><br />
        Geburtsdatum:   <input type="date" name="Geburtsdatum" id="birthDate" /><br />
        Alter:          <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="3" name="age" id="age" /><br />
        Anschrift:      <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="55" name="adress" id="adress" /><br />
        Postleitzahl:   <input type="text" size="5" minlength="4" maxlength="5" name="zipCode" id="zipCode" /><br />
        Ort:            <input type="text" size="40" minlength="2" maxlength="50" name="city" id="city" /><br />
        Telefonnumer:   <input type="tel" size="40" minlength="6" maxlength="30" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" /><br />
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="set">Kontakte speichern</button>
```

Comment: Please try to post only *pertinent* code to your question. I can't see any need for your CSS (or probably much of your HTML), for example. The more concise and focused a question, the more likely someone will answer it.

Comment: Why did you place `localStorage.removeItem()` inside `JSON.stringify()`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove `Object` from `localStorage` use something like `localStorage.removeItem(object);`  If you want to delete multiple elements use something like

```
   let keysToRemove = ['persons #hide', ".flexContact"];
   for (key of keysToRemove) {
       localStorage.removeItem(key);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove the item from the `persons` array, after that you can use the same `localStorage.setItem('persons', JSON.stringify(persons));` call to set the new value in localstorage